# how to make columns of primefaces datatable clickable

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, datatable

I'm using a primefaces datatable and trying to make it clickable without using a javascript. Can anyone help me?

Here is my code. By clicking rows, I want to invoke a method.

```
<p:dataTable id="examplej" class="table couple-table" rowKey="#{info.id}" selectionMode="single" selection="#{bb.detail(info)}" rowIndexVar="rowIndex"
                     var="info" value="#{bb.coupleList}" rows="10" paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
                     rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15" paginator="true" emptyMessage="お探しの地域では見つかりませんでした">
  <p:column class="column-couple">
                <h:outputText value="#{info.addressOne}" />
            </p:column>
```

This is a method which i want to invoke by clicking rows.

```
                <p:commandLink action="#{bb.detail(info)}"/>
```

when i run my webapp, i get this error now.

> javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'java.lang.String' does not have the property 'id'.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: how about the rowSelect event?? `<p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{bean.method}" />`

Answer (score 0):

It can be done via `selection` and `selectionMode` attributes in `<p:datatable>` component. In selection you can specify action in backing bean what would you like to do with selected object. It is clearly documented and presented on [primefaces showcase site](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/selection.xhtml)

Comment: i did it but i found out that i have to add rowKey and did but it doesnt work.

Comment: exception shows clearly that info object have no id parameter because it is a String object. rowkey attribute is used to identify the selected row(s). so it should be binded to object's field which are presented in data table. I don't know what is info object in your case, however for sure it has no id property